# confusion about dijkstra algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

According to the Algorithms book *Corman*, Dijkstra is applicable for only those graphs whose all edges have non negative weights.
Does that mean, if there is any edge with negative weight it will not work for whole of the graph?
or
Will it not count that negative weight edge?
Please indicate which one is right?

Comment: Since it says, "...is applicable for **only those graphs** whose all edges have non-negative weights" then that means the algorithm does not apply to the whole graph. If it only pertained to handling the edge, it would say so specifically, unless the text book has very poor wording. Although since the grammar in your quote from the book isn't correct, I'm not sure you have given an exact quotation.

Answer (score 7):

Dijkstra algorithm can work on a graph of some negative edges sometimes,like:

```
A-->B-->C
```

while `w(A, B) = -1` and `w(B, C) = -2`.

**But when there is at least one negative edge, it can't prove to be always right.** like:

```
A-->B-->C-->D
 \         /
  \ _____ /
```

where `w(A, B) = 1`, `w(B, C) = 3`, `w(C, D) = -5` ,`w(A, D) = 2`.

If you choose A as sourcepoint, you will get the length of shortest path from A to D is `2` by Dijkstra algorithm, not `-1` in fact.

It is because that Dijkstra algorithm is a greedy algorithm, and its proof procedure of correctness uses that all its edges is non-negative to obtain a contradiction.
About its proof procedure, you can look it up at Theorem 24.6 (Correctness of Dijkstra’s algorithm) ,Introduction to Algorithm.

Comment: thank you so much for this explanation. the main issue is that it can work on negative weight edge but not necessarily provides the right solution. (cause it is greedy) am i right??

Comment: @Shubhanshu That's about it. Negative edges might mess up the order in which Dijkstra's algorithm processes nodes, which can lead to wrong solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The major problem with negative edges are **negative cycles**. If a graph contains a negative cycle between vertex S and vertex T, then there is no shortest path between S and T. Dijkstra finds a shortest path, which is incorrect.

Thus, negative edges are not only ignored but contribute to entirely false solutions.

An alternative is Bellman-Ford algorithm which finds those negative cycles in it's |V|-th iteration.

Comment: Negative cycles are not necessary to mess up Dijkstra, you can have a DAG with negative weighted edges for which Dijkstra fails; this answer seems misleading.

Comment: @michael franzen according to you if there is any negative edge in the graph(either in cycle or not) we should not consider it.. right??